How do I apply for a Kenyan passport while living in Ireland?
I'm a dual Kenyan/Irish citizen who wants to travel back home this Christmas. The problem is that my old passport expired and went missing. I've emailed the Kenyan Embassy in Dublin but they say that I need to get biometrics and a Kenyan ID which I also don't have and their embassy doesn't provide the service.
What options do I have?

do you have an Irish passport? Is traveling on that an option?

Have you read https://www.kenyaembassyireland.net/visa-and-consular/consular-services/kenya-passports/? Did you file a lost/stolen passport report with Garda? Do you have a birth certificate? Did you declare dual citizenship? Did you apply for an ID card? If they require biometrics and don’t do it in Dublin, surely they pointed you to a way to have them recorded? Maybe you need to use the devices of the embassy in London?
